# running urllib2 with progressbar calls crashes program

Tags: python, download, tkinter, progress-bar, ttk

Hi so I am having an issue with my code (probably not urllib2 itself) but it wont create a progress bar and crashes. But downloads my file after waiting for the code to finish. Is there anyway I can prevent the hanging and possibly break down the download into smaller chunks as I have little experience with python... My code is below:

```
def iPod1():
pb = ttk.Progressbar(orient ="horizontal",length = 200, mode ="indeterminate")
pb.pack(side="top") 
pb.start()
download = "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/whited00r/7.1/Whited00r71-iPodTouch1G.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fwhited00r%2Ffiles%2F7.1%2F&ts=1405674672&use_mirror=softlayer-ams"
request = urllib2.urlopen( download)
pb.start()
output = open("Whited00r71-iPodTouch1G.zip", "wb")
output.write(request.read())
output.close()
pb.stop
tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Done", message="Download complete. Please follow the installation instructions provided in the .html file.")
```

Comment: Show full error message. There is number of line with problem - mark this line in code.

Comment: Did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? Did you get any message in console/terminal/cmd.exe when you closed it ?

Comment: Does it really stop for good? Your code will definitely block/freeze the GUI during the whole download but should go on afterwards.

Comment: After the download it does start responding again. Is there a way I could avoid blocking/freezing the GUI. I know about threading but I don't have much of an idea as to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hanging/freezing of the GUI can be avoided by moving the download into its own thread. As the GUI must not be changed from another thread than the one the Tk mainloop is running in, we have to check regularly if the download thread has finished. This is usually done by repeatedly schedule a deferred function call with the `after()` method on widget objects.

Not reading the whole file into memory before writing it into a local file can be done with `shutil.copyfileobj()`.

```
import shutil
import tkMessageBox
import ttk
import urllib2
from threading import Thread

IPOD_1_URL = (
    'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/whited00r/7.1/'
    'Whited00r71-iPodTouch1G.zip'
    '?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fwhited00r%2Ffiles%2F7.1%2F'
    '&ts=1405674672'
    '&use_mirror=softlayer-ams'
)


def download(url, filename):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, output_file)


def check_download(thread, progress_bar):
    if thread.is_alive():
        progress_bar.after(500, check_download, thread, progress_bar)
    else:
        progress_bar.stop()
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(
            title='Done',
            message='Download complete. Please follow the installation'
                ' instructions provided in the .html file.'
        )


def start_download_for_ipod1():
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(
        orient='horizontal', length=200, mode='indeterminate'
    )
    progress_bar.pack(side='top')
    progress_bar.start()
    thread = Thread(
        target=download, args=(IPOD_1_URL, 'Whited00r71-iPodTouch1G.zip')
    )
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    check_download(thread, progress_bar)
```

Comment: @itechy21 That's not the function to be called by a button then.  The `start_download_for_ipod1()` function is the one that starts the download.